# How do I use data in package_data from source code?

Tags: python, build, setuptools, distutils, distribute

In setup.py, I have specified package_data like this:

```
packages=['hermes'],
package_dir={'hermes': 'hermes'},
package_data={'hermes': ['templates/*.tpl']},
```

And my directory structure is roughly

```
hermes/
 |
 | docs/
 | ...
 | hermes/
    | 
    | __init__.py
    | code.py
    | templates
        |
        | python.tpl
 |
 | README
 | setup.py
```

The problem is that I need to use files from the templates directory in my source code so I can write out python code (this project is a parser generator).  I can't seem to figure out how to properly include and use these files from my code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The standard [pkgutil module's `get_data()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) will calculate the path to your data, relative to your package, and retrieve the data for you via whatever module loader Python used to import the `hermes` package:

```py
import pkgutil
data = pkgutil.get_data('hermes', 'templates/python.tpl')
```

Of course in certain cases you could just read your data using a path calculated from `hermes.__file__`, but if you plan to distribute your project, consider that it may be installed in different ways on the end user's machine: as plain files, deployed in a zipped egg archive, etc. In the latter case, your `hermes` module will have been imported by Python using a `zipimporter`, preventing you from doing a normal `open(path).read()`:

```py
>>> import hermes
>>> hermes.__loader__
<zipimporter object "/home/pat/.cascade/virt/foo/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo-0.0.0-py2.6.egg">
```

If you're okay with adding a runtime dependency on the `distribute` codebase, you may want to consider looking at the [`pkg_resources module`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html), which can give you the same result but adds other capabilities.

```py
import pkg_resources
data = pkg_resources.resource_string('hermes', 'templates/python.tpl')
```

Comment: one can use `__name__` instead specifying module name directly, therefore `data = pkg_resources.resource_string('hermes', 'templates/python.tpl')` becomes `data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, 'templates/python.tpl')`

Comment: please use `path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('hermes', 'templates/python.tpl')` if you just want to get the path of the package_data, and read it by yourself.