# Module path dependencies

Tags: python

Lets assume the following structure of directories for a project

```
<root>
  __init__.py
  helloworld.py
<moduleOne>
  f.txt
  __init__.py
  printfile.py
```

where root and moduleOne are directories

Content of helloworld.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import helloworld.printfile
printf()
```

Content of moduleOne/printfile

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f = open('f.txt')

def printf():
    print 'print file'
    print f

if __name__ == '__main__':
   printf()
```

My issue:

From moduleOne/ the execution of printfile is ok, but from root/, if i run helloworld.py the following error happens:

```
import moduleOne.printfile
File "/root/moduleOne/printfile.py", line 5, in <module>
 f = open('f.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f.txt'
```

How to solve this in python?

[Edited]

I solved (more or less) this issue with a "workaround", but stil have a problem:

My solution:

In moduleOne/printfile

```
import sys
fname = 'moduloOne/f.txt'

def printf():

    f = open(fname)
    print 'print file'  
    print f

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fname = 'f.txt'
    printf()
```

But....

lets say i have a new directory, from the root, called etc, then the new structure is:

```
<root>
  __init__.py
  helloworld.py
<moduleOne>
  f.txt
  __init__.py
  printfile.py
<etc>
  f2.txt
```

And now i need to acess etc/f2.txt from moduleOne/printfile. how?

Comment: Have you tried f = open('moduleOne/f.txt')?

Comment: I tried this (now), works from <root> but fail from <moduleOne>:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'moduleOne/f.txt'

Comment: Do you need to access 'f.txt' from both modules?

Comment: Yes, actualy i need acess f.txt (a configuration file) from others modules.

Comment: Is 'f.txt' in root or moduleOne?

Comment: No matter, but i need access to f.txt in all modules, for example: root/module1/submodul1. I need acess to f.txt on all three modules.

Comment: You might need to put the full system link to the file then instead of 'f.txt' put the full path to the file.

Comment: I can't do it, the program will run on more of the one environment (different).

Comment: Have you listed the contents of helloworld.py correctly? Should it be 'import moduleOne.printfile'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more abstraction.

1. Don't hard-code the file path in `printfile.py`
2. Don't access a global in the `printf` function.
3. Do accept a file handle as a parameter to the `printf` function:

   ```
   def printf(file_handle):
       print 'print file'
       print file_handle
   ```
4. In a script that *does* actually need to know the path of `f.txt` (I guess `helloworld.py` in your case), put it there, open it, and pass it to `printf`:

   ```
   from moduleOne.printfile import printf

   my_f_file = open('/path/to/f.txt')
   printf(my_f_file)
   ```
5. Better yet, get the file path from the command line

   ```
   import sys

   from moduleOne.printfile import printf

   input_file_path = sys.argv[1]
   my_f_file = open(input_file_path)
   printf(my_f_file)
   ```

**EDIT**: You said on [your Google+ cross-post](https://plus.google.com/101194501855592591221/posts/TXS86SRvpg3):

> full path is problem, the program will run on differents environments.

If you're trying to distribute your program to other users and machines, you should look into [making a distribution package](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) (see side note 3 below), and using `package_data` to include your configuration file, and `pkgutil` or `pkg_resources` to access the configuration file. See [How do I use data in package_data from source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897666/how-do-i-use-data-in-package-data-from-source-code)

Some side-notes:

1. Represent directories as the directory name with a trailing slash, à la the conventions of [the `tree` command](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/): `/` instead of `<root>`, `moduleOne/` instead of `<moduleOne>`
2. You're conflating "module" with "package". I suggest you rename `moduleOne/` to `packageOne/`. A directory with an `__init__.py` file constitutes a package. A file ending in a `.py` extension is a module. Modules can be part of packages by physically existing inside a directory with an `__init__.py` file. Packages can be part of other packages by being a physical subdirectory of a parent directory with an `__init__.py` file.
3. Unfortunately, the term "package" is overloaded in Python and also can mean a collection of Python code for distribution and installation. See [the Python Packaging Guide glossary](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/glossary.html).