# Loading sqlite database in python distribution

Tags: python, build, setuptools, distribute

In setup.py I've specified package_data as the following:

```
packages=['londontweetgrabber'],
package_dir={'londontweetgrabber': 'londontweetgrabber'},
package_data={'londontweetgrabber': ['data/data.db']},
```

My directory hierarchy is roughly as follows:

```
londontweetgrabber/
 |
 | docs/
 | ...
 | londontweetgrabber/
    | 
    | __init__.py
    | authentication.py
    | data
        |
        | data.db
 |
 | README
 | setup.py
```

What I'd like to do is use sqlite3 to load the file in data.db. Trying a variation of a solution found here ([How do I use data in package_data from source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897666/how-do-i-use-data-in-package-data-from-source-code)) I can verify that the data is being loaded now, but sqlite is complaining about a table not existing that I know does. I want this data.db file to be distributed with the python package I am writing as I depend on it for what I want to do.

The code I have at the moment for loading and failing to load sqlite:

```
import sqlite3
import pkgutil


def get_conn():
    data = pkgutil.get_data('londontweetgrabber', 'data/data.db')
    print data

    return sqlite3.connect(data)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually passing *data* (the contents of `data.db`) to [`sqlite3.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect). It however expects a path to your DB like `/data/data.db`.

See [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data):

> The function returns a binary string that is the contents of the
>   specified resource.

You can instead use [`pkg_resources.resource_filename()`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#resource-extraction) to build a proper filesystem path to your `data.db`:

```
import sqlite3
import pkg_resources

db_path = pkg_resouces.resource_filename('londontweetgrabber', 'data/data.db')
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
```