# How can I package and use an icon within a tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter, setuptools

I try to install and run package with gui app in `tkinter`. I am not able to display app icon after installation. What should I change to make it possible? Here is my package directory tree:

```
gui_app/
 | gui_app/
    | __init__.py
    | __main__.py
 | img/
    | icon.gif
 | setup.py
```

`setup.py` contains:

```
from setuptools import setup
from gui_app import __version__

setup(
    name='gui_app',
    version=__version__,
    packages=['gui_app'],
    data_files=[('', ['img/icon.gif'])],
    entry_points={'gui_scripts': ['gui_app = gui_app.__main__:main'],},
)
```

To load my icon I have tried different approaches described here: [pkgutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897666/how-do-i-use-data-in-package-data-from-source-code), 
[importlib.resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package). Unfortunately none of them worked for me. I may do something wrong. Here is code which I ended up with:

```
import tkinter as tk
from importlib.abc import ResourceReader as res

def get_path_before_install():
    return 'img/icon.gif'

def get_path_after_install():
    return res.resource_path('.', 'icon.gif')

def display_gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    icon_path = get_path_after_install()
    icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=str(icon_path))
    root.iconphoto(False, icon)
    root.mainloop()

def main():
    display_gui()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

When I use `$ pip install .` and then `$ gui_app` it produces `FileNotFoundError`. How can I correct it to display icon after installation?

Comment: Instead of `data_files` it should be [`package_data`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package_data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `package_data` is data located in a Python package. So make sure the directory containing the file is an actual Python package (you might want to add an `__init__.py` file in there), and make sure this package is correctly added to your distributions (*sdist* and *bdist*).

So probably for your case, something like the following recommandations could help:

- move the image to `gui_app/img/icon.gif`
- add `gui_app/img/__init__.py` (you might see advice saying it's not necessary, if you truly understand that advice and its implications, then feel free to follow it)
- add `gui_app.img` to the list used as argument for the `packages` parameter in the `setuptools.setup` function call
- adjust the code accordingly

Comment: I have moved icon and added `__init__.py`. Then appended packages list with `gui_app.img`. Modified data to: `package_data={'gui_app.img': ['gui_app/img/*.gif'],},` and used `res.resource_path('gui_app.img', 'icon.gif')`. I still get `FileNotFoundError`. Where am I doing mistake? Updated code on [Github](https://github.com/ethru/gui_app/tree/adjusted_to_answer).

Comment: Check the content of your _sdist_ and _bdist_ (most likely a _wheel_). Make sure to clean the `*.egg-info` directory between attempts. There might be an issue with the argument for the `package_data` parameter. Maybe use the following as a reference to help you debug: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sinoroc answer and linked materials I finally found working solution for me. First I made changes in directory structure (moved `icon.gif` and added `MANIFEST.in`):

```
gui_app/
 | gui_app/
    | __init__.py
    | __main__.py
    | icon.gif
 | MANIFEST.in
 | setup.py
```

Then added one line `include gui_app/icon.gif` to `MANIFEST.in`. Next I replaced `package_data` in `setup.py` with just `include_package_data=True`. Here is modified file:

```
from setuptools import setup
from gui_app import __version__

setup(
    name='gui_app',
    version=__version__,
    packages=['gui_app'],
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={'gui_scripts': ['gui_app = gui_app.__main__:main'],},
)
```

Finally I got rid off `ResourceReader.resource_path('gui_app', 'icon.gif')`. In his place I used `pkgutil.get_data('gui_app', 'icon.gif')`. `__main__.py` contains now:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pkgutil

def get_icon():
    return pkgutil.get_data('gui_app', 'icon.gif')

def display_gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    icon = tk.PhotoImage(data=get_icon())
    root.iconphoto(False, icon)
    root.mainloop()

def main():
    display_gui()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```